# Combining Javascripts issue

Tags: javascript

Hi I have 2 javascript that I need to combine can you tell me what is the best way to do this. 1st js:

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('Test');
document.write(MyDiv1.innerHTML);
```

This outputs into numeric ID (ex. 67)

Now I need that ID to go to a dfp script key value

```
googletag.pubads().definePassback('8888888/rr1-220x220', [[220,220]]).setTargeting('adshere',['ID-GOES-Here']).display();
```

Can you give me some advice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
googletag.pubads().definePassback('8888888/rr1-220x220', [[220,220]]).setTargeting('adshere',[document.getElementById('Test').innerHTML]).display()
```

Comment: @JamesTan Why didn't it work? Did u get any exceptions?

Comment: does it work if you put the value directly in the script ? Open the console with F12 and tell me what you see before.

Comment: click on console tab maybe a message is present

Comment: some script can't be loaded if you are in local. you have to use a server like uwamp or xampp and use the 127.0.0.1 url or do it directly on your website

Comment: You probably have made a syntax error/typo in your page scripts (as logged)

Comment: Thanks guys! it's working now I had to change the dfp script to asynchronous from a passback script and that fixed the issue.